# How to choose rim strip width?

Tags: wheels, rims, rim-tape

After referencing [How do I know which size and type of rim strip to buy?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/540/how-do-i-know-which-size-and-type-of-rim-strip-to-buy)  I still couldn't use any of the answers to identify the correct width of rim tape to choose.

Velox tape comes in narrow (10mm), wide (17mm) or ATB (22mm) sizes.  What rim widths or styles are each of these sizes appropriate for or how can I determine which width is appropriate to use?

I'm not sure if the same rules apply for very large rims either. Should I just use the largest size, ATB tape (22mm), on very wide rims like velocity blunt 35 (35mm wide) and dually (45mm wide)?

Comment: It isn't really all that critical.  You don't want the strip so much wider than the inside of the rim that it will climb the wall enough to interfere with the bead, and you don't want it so narrow that it doesn't completely cover the holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the rim strip to just cover the flat bottom of the wheel. You just need to cover the spoke holes. If the rim strip is too wide it will climb up the sides of the wheel and potentially interfere with the tire bead seating properly.

Comment: So it's fine if it covers the spoke holes, but does not cover the whole flat bottom?

Comment: The rim strip should cover as much of the flat part as possible to keep from moving off center too far. You want the rim strip on the flat of the rim, not the sides.