# Which rim tape for 700x28 tires?

Tags: maintenance, rims, rim-tape

Which rim tape should i use for 700x28 tires? I can only find 700x17 or 700x14...

I just measured my 26" and the (outside) base of the rim is 24mm... and i used rim tape that is 20mm wide... it fitted fine.

Now for my 700 tire, the base of the rim measures some 23mm... almost the same as the 26"...  yet the tape will be 3mm short. will that make any difference?

Also, would i be able to use the 26" tape on the 700?

Comment: Really you are asking if the rim tape is short will it make a difference.  And it is rim tape - not tire tape.  You fit the rim not the tire.

Comment: You need to cover all the nipples with the tape.  If there's a gap between nipples that's not a big deal.  And the best choice for width is the widest that will just fit in the recess of the rim.  You don't want any tape overlapping into the area where the tire bead will seat.

Comment: See related question http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/how-to-choose-rim-strip-width

Comment: @Blam sorry, i wrote tire there by mistake. just meant 700c rims.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it covers the back sides of the nipples and isn't interfering with the bead you'll be fine.

The tape is just there to protect your tube from and sharp edges, getting worn through over time or blowing out down a spoke hole.

<sub>See [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/flats.html#rimtapes)</sub>

Comment: i know all that :) just want to know if a tape width of 17mm on a rim that i can measure the outside as over 23mm will be too thin and move around exposing a nibble or not... don't want to 1. remove tire. 2. buy tape. 3. measure and see it is not a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the rim design. Generally you want the tape to cover the spoke holes, but only just. Measure the width at the bottom flat of the inside of the rim.

Or you could get Veloplugs, these are plastic inserts that snap into the spoke holes and are both lighter and less hassle than rim tape. [image: VeloPlugs Red]

http://www.togoparts.com/articles/article.php?artid=201

Long term, I sometimes have problems with rim tape creeping slightly and exposing just a small bit of spoke hole. This always leads to recurring flats until you find
where the tape has shifted. This happens more with some rims than others.

The only gotcha with VeloPlugs is that they come in two sizes (Red and Yellow) and you need to get the size that matches your rim.

Comment: Nice! never heard of those before... but don't see how they protect around the steam (not that tape does a great job there either)

Comment: ok, i looked to buy those... there are a million types and i have no idea which one i need before I take my tire out :( and i only want to do that when i'm ready to put it back on and not remove it until the next flat :) will use tape this time and see if i remember to take notes for the future. thanks

Comment: Tubes are reinforced with thicker rubber around the stem, the tape does nothing to prevent flats near the stem.