# How do I work out tube and rim strip size

Tags: innertube

I have a Schwinn Men's Volare 1200 Bike, 700c. Recently had a flat. I am confused. What size tubes do I need to buy? And also the rim strip snapped. What size rim strip should I order

Comment: Generally tube size is expressed in terms if tire size, but a given tube will often fit a range of tire widths.  (And sometimes the same tube will be sold as both a 700c and a 27" tube, since tubes can flex quite a bit to serve both sizes.)  You want to pick a 700c tube such that the width of your tire (as listed on the sidewall) falls in the width range specified for the tube.

Comment: As to rim strip size, you want a strip that is as wide as possible but still fits the "gully" in the center of the rim, without climbing its walls too far.

Answer (score 4):

You need to know what caused the flat first (recommended reading [here](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/flats.html)); it may merit replacing the tire itself depending on cause.

The tube will be 700c x a-b where your tire size is between a and b.

The rim strip needs to be matched to the rim width. See [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/540/how-do-i-know-which-size-and-type-of-rim-strip-to-buy) to measure it. Depending on why the rim tape snapped, you may need to make some adjustments to the wheel itself.

If you take the wheel+tire to your local bike shop, they should be able to sort you out with this very quickly and even install the new tube and rim tape quickly for some nominal fee.